# Retrieving old queries

Tags: db2, aix

I'd like to see the queries a user executed within a date range. Is this possible? If so, how?

For example, a query was executed a few days ago, and I'd like to retrieve it. Manual queries are not run very often, so my results will not be large.

Comment: Belongs to a different stackoverflow site (Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows does not track a historical record of queries.

If you need to see a history of statements executed in your database, you have 2 options:

1. Create an [audit policy](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050607.html) for the database (for the `execute` category)
2. Create/enable an [event monitor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000915.html) for statements (or activities if you have Workload Management)

Both of these options can have performance considerations, so use them wisely.